# Google login for server-side apps

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm following the Google guide for signing in with Google and sending the access code to a server:

Guide here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_6_send_the_authorization_code_to_the_server

I have two really simple questions:

- How does the closure in the jQuery click event know about `auth2`? If you run this code in Chrome, you'll get an error saying `auth2` is undefined. How would I go about fixing that error?

Run from onload:

```
function start() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({...});
    });
}
```

jQuery click handler

```
(function($) {
    $('#signinButton').click(function() {
        auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(signInCallback);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

- How is `signInCallback` passed information? Is this part of the callback process?

The code:

```
function signInCallback(authResult) {
    if(authResult['code']) {
        $.ajax({...});
    } else { ... }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `gapi.auth2` in the click event handler? Assuming `gapi` is set in the global / window scope.

Comment: Not sure, I'm based this info off the guide. Maybe take a look and drop some knowledge?

Comment: Off a glance, it looks like they are just setting `auth2` onto the window scope, and then accessing it from the click handler. They really should make that more clear on the guide. Make sure you init the auth2 variable in the head, and your click-handler at the end of the page. Furthermore, check to make sure auth2 is set before proceeding with the click. I assume they're loading the auth2 library using async. You could only enable the button after the auth loads.

Comment: That totally did it. You should write up an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the client api at the top of the HTML file:

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
```

and then initializing:

```
function start() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({...});
    });
}
```

also in the header will do the trick. The guide says this, but neglects to state that it won't really work otherwise.